# Keep contents from shifting when browser is minimized or resized

Tags: css, html

I am new to this, so I have this problem where the contents in the page will be shifted when the browser is minimized. When the browser is minimized, the contents including the logo will be shifted and the contents will be shifted out of the blue transparent background.

here is my css codes

```
   #full-screen-background-image {
 z-index: -999;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 1300px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 }

  .whole{
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 1242px;
  width: 1000px;
  }

  .clear{
margin: 0 auto;
clear: both;
}

 .logo {
width: 460px;
height: 170px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.fax {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 480px;
 height: 110px;
 margin-right: 267px;
 }

.fax p {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 55px;
    width: 394px;
}

.faxLogo{
    float: left;
height:60px;
width: 60px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-left: -385px;
}


 .tel{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 480px;
height: 70px;
margin-right: 267px;
}

.telDetails{
float:left;
height: 10px;
}

.telLogo{
float: left;
height:60px;
width: 60px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-left: 65px;
}

.tel p {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

 .locationLogo{
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 65px;
}




.location{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 500px;
 }

.location p {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    float: left;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: -35px;
    margin-left: 160px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.detail1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.detail1 p{
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 130px;
}

.detail2 {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.detail2 p{
    margin-top: -20px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 45px;
}
```

here is my HTML codes

```
<div class="clear" style="height: 445px;"></div>

<div class="whole">

    <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo_3.jpg" /></div>

    <div class="clear" style="height:50px;"></div>

    <div class="detail1">
        <p>TEXT</p>

    </div>
    <div class="detail2">
        <p>TEXT</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clear" style="margin-top:-53px;"></div>

    <div class="location">
        <div class="locationLogo">
            <img src="images/location.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="locationDetails">
            <p style="width: 500px;">TEXT<br />TEXT<br />TEXT</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tel">
        <div class="telLogo" style="width: 10px;">
            <img src="images/tel.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="telDetails">
            <p style="width: 365px;">TEXT</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fax">
        <div class="faxLogo" style="width: 10px;">
            <img src="images/fax.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="faxDetails">
            <p style="width: 394px;">TEXT</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Here every thing works well. where is the issue?

Comment: the issue is that content keeps shifting down. I'm not sure if its my desktop screen size that is affecting it. Can i know your screen size?

Comment: screen resolution. 1440 X 900.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the content will shift is due to my screen size? My screen size is 1680 x 1050.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content inside your transparent box moves when the window resizes but your transparent box is part of the background image. Use the oil rig as a background image and put your content in a div. Something like this:

```css
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>SOME CONTENT HERE</li>
        <li>SOME CONTENT HERE</li>
        <li>SOME CONTENT HERE</li>
        <li>SOME CONTENT HERE</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can now place the div wherever you see fit on your page.